# How to handle Second datepicker for return journey in Abhibus by Selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am writing code to select journey date and return journey date but return journey not getting selected. driver directly jumping to search button without entering return date.

```
public class Callender {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.abhibus.com/");
        //to select leaving from
        WebElement source =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='source']"));
        source.clear();
        source.sendKeys("Tenal");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        source.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        //to select destination
        WebElement destination =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='destination']"));
        destination.clear();
        destination.sendKeys("Hyderaba");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        destination.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);


        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"datepicker1\"]"));
        String journeydate="04-10-2019";
        selectJourney(driver,element,journeydate);

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"datepicker2\"]"));
        String returndate="06-10-2019";
        selectRJourney(driver,element1,returndate);
        //to click search button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"roundTrip\"]/a")).click();
    }
    public static void selectRJourney(WebDriver driver, WebElement element1, String returndate) {
        JavascriptExecutor je=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        je.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','"+returndate+"');", element1);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public static void selectJourney(WebDriver driver,WebElement element,String journeydate) {
        JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','"+journeydate+"');",element);
    }
```

Can you please help me to figure out what went wrong or probably what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see the results when you run the script? or a calendar opening up?

Comment: I think you have to select the date from the calendar rather setting the value, as the selected date is not updated for value attribute (check the html before and after running the javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below code. By using `document.getElementById('datepicker1').value = "Your_Date"` to set the caleneder value.

```
String journeydate="04-10-2019";
selectJourney(driver,journeydate);

Thread.sleep(3000);
String returndate="06-10-2019";
selectRJourney(driver,returndate);
```

**I have modified your code:**

```
public static void selectRJourney(WebDriver driver, String returndate) {
    JavascriptExecutor je=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    je.executeScript("document.getElementById('datepicker2').value = '"+returndate+"';");

}
public static void selectJourney(WebDriver driver,String journeydate) {
    JavascriptExecutor je=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    je.executeScript("document.getElementById('datepicker1').value = '"+journeydate+"';");

}
```

**Suggestions:**

- Instead of using `xpath`, you can easly use `id`.
- `JavascriptExecutor` is not recommended if you want to perform real
  testing.
- `selectRJourney` and `selectJourney` are duplicate method and contain same code. try to merge them into one.

********************** ***EDITED*** *************************

```
String journeydate="04-10-2019";
selectDateFromCalender(driver,"datepicker1",journeydate);

Thread.sleep(3000);
String returndate="06-10-2019";
selectDateFromCalender(driver,"datepicker2",returndate);
```

**You can create the common method `selectDateFromCalender` and pass the date picker id as a argument:**

```
public static void selectDateFromCalender(WebDriver driver, String datePickerId, String returndate) {
    JavascriptExecutor je=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    je.executeScript("document.getElementById('"+datePickerId+"').value = '"+returndate+"';");

}
```

***** **HACK AS PER YOUR LEAD REQUIREMENT** ******

```
driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker1")).click();
int currentSelectedDate = Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-state-highlight")).getText());
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-state-highlight")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker2")).click();
if(currentSelectedDate>=30)
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ui-state-default'][contains(text(),'1')]")).click();
else
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ui-state-default'][contains(text(),'"+(currentSelectedDate+1)+"')]")).click();
```

Comment: Have you modified your code as mention above?? It should able to solve your problem..

Comment: Thanks bro, if I am able to solve your problem, kindly accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this method.
I used Selenide which manages webdriver automatically.

You can modify date selection to match your needs.

**BusSearchTest.java**

```
    package com.abhibus;

    import com.codeborne.selenide.Configuration;
    import com.codeborne.selenide.SelenideElement;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    import static com.codeborne.selenide.Condition.appear;
    import static com.codeborne.selenide.Condition.text;
    import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.$;
    import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open;


    public class BusSearchTest {

        @DataProvider
        public static Object[][] itineraries() {
            return new String[][]{
                    {"Tenal", "Tenali", "Hyderaba", "Hyderabad", "Tenali → Hyderabad"}
            };
        }

        @BeforeTest
        public void setup() {
            Configuration.timeout = 10 * 1000;
        }

        @BeforeMethod
        public void beforeMethod() {
            open("https://www.abhibus.com/");
        }

        @Test(description = "Search Buses", dataProvider = "itineraries")
        public void busSearch(String from, String fromExpected, String to, String toExpected, String expected) {
            //to select leaving from
            $("#source").setValue(from);
            $("#ui-id-1 li.ui-menu-item")
                    .shouldHave(text(fromExpected))
                    .shouldBe(appear)
                    .click();
            //to select destination
            $("#destination").setValue(to);
            $("#ui-id-2 li.ui-menu-item")
                    .shouldHave(text(toExpected))
                    .shouldBe(appear)
                    .click();

            // from date: 04-October-2019
            $("#datepicker1").click();
            SelenideElement datePicker1 = $(".ui-datepicker-group-first");
            while (!datePicker1.find("span.ui-datepicker-month").text().trim().equals("October")) {
                $(".ui-datepicker-group-last").find("span").shouldHave(text("Next")).click();
            }
            datePicker1.findAll("tr td a").filterBy(text("4")).first().click();

            // to date: 06-October-2019
            $("#datepicker2").click();
            SelenideElement datePicker2 = $(".ui-datepicker-group-first");
            while (!datePicker2.find("span.ui-datepicker-month").text().trim().equals("October")) {
                $(".ui-datepicker-group-last").find("span").shouldHave(text("Next")).click();
            }
            datePicker2.findAll("tr td a").filterBy(text("6")).first().click();

            // click search
            $("a[title='Search Buses']").click();

            // assert search page
            $("#SubHead1way h1").shouldHave(text(expected));
        }
    }
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>tech.webisto</groupId>
        <artifactId>abhibus-tests</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                        <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>test.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.8</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

You may checkout code here:
https://github.com/WebistoTech/AbhiBusTests.git

Comment: can we use selenium and selenide together ??  because i dont have knowledge about selenide

Comment: It would not be that useful if you mixed together. But you should be able to.

Comment: if you can write the same code in selenium , help me out bro ..team lead asked me to write generic code and without hardcoding dates..but i need the code in selenium only ..